# Re-query and refresh not working on main form after popup form edits

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I have a main form, CaregiverFactSheet, that displays all types of information. It has a button, Edit, that opens the caregiverDemographics popup form where the user can edit the caregivers address.

From the main form I use the following code to open the popup form:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "CaregiverInformation", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
```

The user can edit and save the data then close the form. However, when the popup form closes it does not update the main form with the new information. I have tried numerous re-queries and refreshes on many events on both the popup and main form.

On the main form the user initially selects from a combobox to load a caregiver which updates unbounded textboxes using DLookup in the AfterUpdate event. Would this prevent me from updating the main form from a popup?

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted, the form will load "normal" rather than modal. The primary difference is that a modal dialog will halt execution until return (form is closed).

So if you have a process like this:

```
Open Form With WindowMode Normal
Refresh Data Based on Form Edits
```

Then the "Refresh Data" will happen immediately after opening the form (i.e. before the form has been edited).

If you set `WindowMode` to `Dialog` or `Modal`, then the user will have time to use the form before updates. Check the documentation for proper syntax.

Comment: I've changed the line to this        DoCmd.OpenForm "AssignedCaregivers", , , "[AssignmentID]=" & CaregiverLookup, acFormEdit, acDialog However, I am still getting nothing.

Comment: Also the subform is setup with Popup Yes and Modal Yes